# Can a property be expanded relative to its defining POM and not any child(ren)

Tags: maven

I am trying to set several properties in a parent aggregation POM project which are therefore available to all module projects:

```
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
</modules>
<properties>
    <module1.dir>${project.basedir}</module1.dir>
    <module1.build.dir>4{project.basedir}/build</module1.build.dir>
</properties>
```

The properties relate to various directories I intended them to be evaluated **relative to the parent POM**

I want to refer to the above properties in a second module (module2) like so:

```
${module1.build.dir}
```

However when I look at the effective POM of module2, the following expansion results:

```
<module1.build.dir>_project_root_directory_/module2/build</module1.build.dir>
```

What I would like is the value of `${module1.dir}` etc. to be expanded relative to the parent POM (where it is defined). Is there anyway to do this in Maven or am I going to have to set some environment variables in a script to do this?

The reason for trying to do this is that I am doing an unusual build in that `module1` is a pure native library, `module2` is a JNI library that depends on `module1` and `module3` is a pure Java library that depends directly on `module2`.

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your pom...usually you need need such paths...quirks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, maven does the inheritance 1st (so constructing a leaf pom's effective-pom by combining all of its parents), and only then evaluates properties.

this means properties are always evaluated in the context of the child pom in your case.

this is a requirement for maven to behave properly. look in the [super pom](http://maven-nar.github.io/) and you will see things like:

```
<build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
    ...
</build>
```

which define where sources are looked for and where target classes are written to. they must be evaluated post-inheritance (in the context of a child).

**workaround**
you could use a property value like `${project.parent.basedir}`, or you could "look sideways" by using `../sibling-module/whatever`. neither of these is pretty.

**alternative**
for maven builds involving native components, have you looked at the [maven nar plugin](http://maven-nar.github.io/)? it was developed for these situations specifically.

Comment: Yes, in the end I discovered the `project.parent.basedir` which is not ideal but then I am trying to 'bend' Maven beyond it's envelope of specified behaviour so it's a happy compromise.

Comment: @Kerry - I'd still advise you to look at the NAR plugin, but its a learning curve....